# How to specify Kafka Zookeeper endpoint in Akka Stream Kafka ConsumerSettings

Tags: apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream

I have a Kafka Broker which is running somewhere in cloud and when i am trying to consume from it via the command line consumer tool i can consume messages. But when i am putting the same endpoint in my akka-stream kafka ConsumerSettings its not working.
Eg:- bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper hostname:2181/xxx/yyy --topic topic-name 
This is working for me. But the same thing when i am doing via ConsumerSetting its not working

```
val consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings(actorSystem, new ByteArrayDeserializer, new StringDeserializer)
  .withBootstrapServers("hostname:2181/xxx/yyy")
  .withGroupId(groupID)
  .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")

Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics("topic-name"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you specify --zookeeper you are using the old (and unsecured) consumer. If the cloud based kafka broker is setup properly you should be able to consume using console-consumer with --bootstrap-server param and no --zookeeper. If that doesn't work then the cluster is probably not setup correctly with external advertised.listeners ip or host name. You probably also want to firewall off direct client access to zookeeper.